# G-WAN and Key-Value store in C

Tags: redis, key-value, g-wan, key-value-store

Is it advisable and possible to use an expiration time on the data stored via the Key-Value Store in G-WAN, or is it better and more stable to use a solution like Redis (especially if that involves storing a large number of values) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it advisable and possible to use an expiration time on the data stored via the Key-Value Store in G-WAN?

Possible, certainly. See the `kv.c` example about how to use both `kv_do()` to process expirations and a dedicated index for time values.

Advisable? Actually, this is the way G-WAN works since 2009. And it does it pretty well.

> or is it better and more stable to use a solution like Redis?

I have never used Redis, nor I benchmarked it in such a test but I remember to have read its code once and, well, I would not bet on it being either faster or more scalable than G-WAN.

Besides, they don't use the same protocol if I am not mistaking. But the G-WAN 'protocol handlers' will let you implement the Redis query language in G-WAN if Redis can't be made to understand HTTP requests.

Why don't you do your own research and write such a (tiny) app, benchmark it, and then submit the results for positive criticism / suggestions to the authors of both Redis and G-WAN?

Then, you will have the answer to your question.